# Importing and transforming txt file into a csv using R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, transformation, txt

I have very little experience with transforming txt data except for very basic transformations and I have been trying for about an hour now to get somewhere using Excel power query and Tidyverse in R.

I have a txt file in the following format, the below example shows data on three vegetation survey plots, though my actual data is over 1600 plots:

```
Plot 1
CVS: class 49
ELL: No data for 2 species: Betula seedling/sp; Quercus seedling/sp
ELL: Light 5.6; Wetness 5.5; pH 3.9; Fertility 4.2
CSR: 2 species with no data: Betula seedling/sp; Pinus sylvestris
CSR: C: 2.89  S: 2.35  R: 2.33
BIO: 2 species with no data: Betula seedling/sp; Quercus seedling/sp
BIO: Eurasian Boreal-montane 14%
BIO: Eurosiberian Boreo-temperate 14%
BIO: Oceanic Temperate 14%
BIO: European Temperate 14%
BIO: Eurosiberian Temperate 14%
BIO: Circumpolar Temperate 14%
BIO: European Southern-temperate 14%

Plot 2
CVS: class 42
ELL: No data for 2 species: Betula seedling/sp; Quercus seedling/sp
ELL: Light 5.2; Wetness 5.2; pH 4.9; Fertility 5.4
CSR: 2 species with no data: Betula seedling/sp; Tilia [spp]
CSR: C: 2.36  S: 2.79  R: 2.75
BIO: 3 species with no data: Betula seedling/sp; Quercus seedling/sp; Tilia [spp]
BIO: Oceanic Temperate 25%
BIO: European Temperate 50%
BIO: Eurosiberian Temperate 25%

Plot 3
CVS: class 42
ELL: No data for 1 species: Quercus seedling/sp
ELL: Light 4.9; Wetness 5.2; pH 5.9; Fertility 5.5
CSR: C: 2.74  S: 3.25  R: 2.49
BIO: 2 species with no data: Acer pseudoplatanus; Quercus seedling/sp
BIO: Circumpolar Wide-boreal 11%
BIO: Circumpolar Boreo-temperate 11%
BIO: Eurosiberian Wide-temperate 11%
BIO: European Temperate 22%
BIO: Eurosiberian Temperate 11%
BIO: Circumpolar Temperate 11%
BIO: European Southern-temperate 22%
```

I actually don't need to keep much of this data, I need to retain and transform the information in the first two rows and also row 5/6 (CSR) what I need is a table in the following format:

```
PLOT    CVS      C      S      R
 1       49      2.89   2.35   2.33
 2       42      2.36   2.79   2.75
 3       42      2.74   3.25   2.49
```

Is this even possible to do from the existing txt format? I am sadly clueless on this subject and no amount of googling seems to help. All thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: what would a `dput(some_tidyr_object)` look like if you copied `structure(...)` above as data?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to put the "Plot n" row **always in first position**, the CVS: class nn" row in **second position**, and the CSR: C: nn... etc." **ALWAYS in sixth position**?

Because in that case I think I have some Excel formulas that can help you with this result:

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K04fN.png)

The formula are these (startin in the B6 cell):

B column:
=CLEAN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Plot";A1));MID(A1;6;10);""))

C column:
=CLEAN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CVS: class ";A2));MID(A2;12;10);""))

D column:
=CLEAN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CSR: C: ";A2));MID(A6;9;5);""))

E column:
=CLEAN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CSR: C: ";A2));MID(A6;18;5);""))

F column:
=CLEAN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CSR: C: ";A2));MID(A6;27;5);""))

As you can see in the image, when there is one less line in the txt, the data in the excel does not display perfectly. Hence my initial question.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for thank you - except Excel is telling me there is a problem with the formula, annoyingly, I can't see what the p[roblem could be as I'm entering it in the correct B6 cell exactly as it is written. Sigh.